# Rewrite Query with Cartesian product

Tags: t-sql, cartesian

I am not a developer, so need help in rewriting this Query without a inner join as i think that is the core issue. This runs over 20 seconds. Smaller chunks run in under a second. Pl help.

```
select a.compID, b.InitialRT, b.VwRgts, b.UpdRgts, b.InsRgts, b.delRgts, b.Sscrnum , c.UserID
from tablecmpy a, tbldetrght b (nolock)
inner join tableuser c (nolock) on c.GroupID = b.UserId 
where b.RecType='G'  
and b.compID='[ALL]' 
and b.InitialRT+b.VwRgts+b.UpdRgts+b.InsRgts+b.delRgts > 0
```

Comment: It would be extremely unlikely that you would get *faster* results from a cartesian join... let alone results that match your requirements. It seems to me that you need to have a join on `c.groupid = b.groupid` so that's that. Perhaps check out your EXPLAIN and invest your time in appropriate indexes to cover your joins and your `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You already got Cartesian join (old style joins) here `from tablecmpy a, tbldetrght b (nolock)`. Try to use:

```
SELECT  a.compID, 
        b.InitialRT, 
        b.VwRgts, 
        b.UpdRgts, 
        b.InsRgts, 
        b.delRgts, 
        b.Sscrnum, 
        c.UserID
FROM tablecmpy a (nolock)
CROSS JOIN tbldetrght b (nolock)
INNER JOIN tableuser c (nolock) 
    ON c.GroupID = b.UserId 
WHERE b.RecType='G'  
    AND b.compID='[ALL]' 
    AND COALESCE(b.InitialRT,0) + 
        COALESCE(b.VwRgts,0) +
        COALESCE(b.UpdRgts,0) + 
        COALESCE(b.InsRgts,0) +
        COALESCE(b.delRgts,0) > 0
```

I don't know if you have `NULL` in `b.columns`, so I add COALESCE to handle them.